# Google Analytics configuration setting for Drupal multisite (domain and submain)

Tags: 7, multi-sites, google-analytics, subsites

I am working on a `Drupal` mulsite project (`using single database`) and using `Google Analytics` module for this.

I have follow the below steps for GA configuration:

1. Created a domain name `example1.com` and a sub-domain name `example2.com`.
2. Create an account on GA and create property for both of this domain name in GA account. Both property give me two different `Tracking ID` (same as below screenshot).

[image]

3. Into the configuration setting of GA from drupal admin section I have added `Web Property ID` of `example1.com` and into domain setting added both the domain name `example1.com` and `example2.com` into the section of `List of top-level domains` (a same as attached screenshot).

[image]

Now this configuration is only working for `emample1.com`, not for `example2.com`. So can anyone please tell me how can I use `Web Property ID` of domain `exmaple2.php` to get the result?

Comment: I take it doesn't work because those domains have two different UAs, while the module allows you to enter just one.

Answer (score 1):

As Kiamlaluno states, this is likely caused by the fact that the module only allows one UA, while you are trying to track two domains. According to the GA module documentation it can be overridden using code like this in settings.php:

```
<?php
// Override Google Analytics Web Property ID per hostname. 
// Hostnames need to be lower-case!
switch ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
  case 'www.example.com':
  case 'www.example.net':
  case 'forum.example.net':
    $conf['googleanalytics_account'] = 'UA-123456-2';
    break;

  case 'www.example.org':
    $conf['googleanalytics_account'] = 'UA-123456-3';
    break;

  default:
    $conf['googleanalytics_account'] = 'UA-123456-1';
}
?>
```

Documentation can be found [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/37694)