# How to add a javascript snippet to track a 2nd Google Analytics account?

Tags: 7, google-analytics

In my settings for Google Analytics I need to add a javascript snippet in the "after" section, to track a **second** account (the main account works fine).

I added this:

> ga("create", "UA-xxxxxxxx-x",  {"cookieDomain":"auto"}); ga("set",
>   "anonymizeIp", true); ga("send", "pageview");

It does not work at all though. How shall I change this to make it work? The Google Analytics module version is 7.x-2.3.

Note: I don't think this question is a duplicate of "[Google Analytics configuration setting for Drupal multisite (domain and submain)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/160329)": the other question is about two different domains, I have only one domain, which is tracked by 2 accounts. Also under the text box where I am supposed to paste my javascript snippet in the GA module UI, you can find this text: '

> This is useful if you'd like to track a site in two accounts

... which suggests that you really can track 2 accounts for 1 site. My problem is that the snippet I entered does not work. The second account does not recieve any data.

Comment: Hello. No, I don't think this is a duplicate. The other question is about two different domains. I have only one domain, which is tracked by 2 accounts. Also under the text box where I am supposed to paste my javascript snippet in the GA module UI, you can find this text:
'This is useful if you'd like to track a site in two accounts.'.

Comment: What's the difference between this question and [this question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/206440/how-to-add-two-separate-ga-accounts-in-one-drupal-site)? BTW: both questions have an identical answer ...